# How to install Canon 2525 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, 18.04, canon

I am  using Ubuntu 18.04. I am unable  to install Canon 2525 network printer. I have tried using drivers from website.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the ImageRunner 2525 https://www.canon-europe.com/for_work/products/office_print_copy_solutions/office_black_white/imagerunner2525/specification.aspx

then go here https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-2525.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)and click to download and **SAVE** what will be **linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz** and it should end up in the **Downloads** folder

This latest driver was released 18th March 2018 by Canon; they do an excellent job of supporting linux, and it would be good if folks acknowledge this.

Open a terminal; copy each command below; paste each command; line by line into the terminal; hit the **ENTER** key after each paste;

open a terminal with three keys held down: control alt and t; and to paste, right-click at the text prompt in the terminal; the flashing light; and look for PASTE in the menu that appears .....

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz

cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken

sudo ./install.sh
```

Watch the terminal as the final command runs; as it will ask you some questions; it should print thereafter

Comment: The suggested step worked for me. Thanks.